# Using 0b representation to print (printf) float

Tags: c, binary, floating-point, printf

I'm trying to express a fractional number in binary and then have it print out as a float. I've done the fixed point to floating point conversion.

The number in decimal: -342.265625

fixed point: -101010110.010001

32-bit float: 11000011101010110010001000000000

64-bit float (double): 1100000001110101011001000100000000000000000000000000000000000000

*I've double checked with an IEEE 754 Converter

*I'm also aware that printf changes floats into doubles to print them, but declaring it as a double should work? I thought...?

Code:

```
int main()
{

  float floaty = 0b11000011101010110010001000000000;
  double doubley = 0b1100000001110101011001000100000000000000000000000000000000000000;
  printf("Float: %f\n", floaty);
  printf("Double: %lf\n", doubley);

}
```

Output:

```
Float: 3282772480.000000
Double: 13868100853597995008.000000
```

The compiler is gcc and the standard is c99

Comment: `0b` must be a gcc extension. It would be nice if you could find the documentation on how it works with floating point initialization.

Comment: `printf` doesn't change `float`s to `double`s automatically. In many implementations, it just interprets the mem area where the actual argument is as a double. So, please convert your `float`s explicitely to `double` before passing them to `printf`.

Comment: @CST-Link It shouldn't matter for printing `floaty`

Comment: @CST-Link In C, trailing arguments are subject to default argument promotions, which promotes float to double. Specifiers f and lf are valid for double or float. OP is using the best possible option.

Comment: @CST-Link the `printf` format `%f` is for `double` and any `float` argument is promoted to `double` in the same way that for `%d` a `char` argument is promoted to `int`.

Comment: Well... I believe that it *should* matter that `printf` goes 4 more bytes out of a `float`s mem representation, bundles that up with the legitimate value and presents that as a `double`. But, of course, is up to you to decide what *you* believe. :-)

Comment: Haha... apparently I *am* wrong... thanks everybody to opening up my eyes.

Comment: @2501: `0b` is simply GCC's notation for base-2 integers (many other languages have this exact same notation, and IMO, C99 or at least C11 should've added it ... but sadly, they didn't). W.r.t. floating point initialization, it works *exactly* the same as any other integer.

Comment: @TimČas Well, obviously. I was hinting to OP that he's using something that isn't in plain C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the binary constants with some more work.

We will have to assume the floating point represented using IEEE 754, and the system is in little endian:

```
uint32_t value = 0b11000011101010110010001000000000;
float f;
memcpy( &f , &value , sizeof( f ) );
printf( "%f\n" , f );
```

Comment: THANK YOU @2501, I wanted this to work and I am now a very happy man!

Comment: @ZacTaylor Just make sure you document and assert the assumptions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @ZacTaylor The code can cause undefined behavior on certain systems.

Comment: OK I got you! Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

From gcc's [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.0/gcc/Binary-constants.html#Binary-constants):

> The type of these constants follows the same rules as for octal or
>   hexadecimal integer constants, so suffixes like ‘L’ or ‘UL’ can be
>   applied.

So, the binary numbers you assign to float and double are actually  of *integer types* and don't directly map to the bit pattern of the underlying types you assign to.

In other words, this:

```
 float floaty = 0b11000011101010110010001000000000;
 double doubley = 0b1100000001110101011001000100000000000000000000000000000000000000;
```

is equivalent to:

```
 float floaty = 3282772480;
 double doubley = 13868100853597995008;
```

Comment: Is there a way to express them using those binary values?

Comment: @ZacTaylor C doesn't provide direct  provisions to operate at bit levels; the lowest addressable unit is a *byte* in C. You can do as 2501 suggested which will work on most modern systems.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the compiler is trying to help you out. Your literals (0b1...), which by the way is a non-standard extension and should be written as (0x...), are treaded as literals. The compiler then tries its very best to fit those values into the variables you cast them to. As such it produces very big values that are equal to the integer value of your literals.

To directly assign the value of a variable, you have to use unions (or pointers if you don't mind losing a bit of portability). This code works:

```
#include <stdint.h>

union floatint {
    float f;
    uint32_t i;
};

union doubleint {
    double d;
    uint64_t i;
};    

int main()
{
  floatint floaty;
  doubleint doubley;
  floaty.i = 0xC3AB2200;
  doubley.i = 0xC075644000000000; 
  printf("Float: %f\n", floaty.f); // implementation-defined, in your case IEEE 754
  printf("Double: %lf\n", doubley.d); // ditto

}
```

Note that this is the very definition of a union, two (or more) types that share the same representation, but are treated differently.

Comment: Thanks @LambdaBeta, is there any way to express them using the binary values I originally posted?

Comment: Pointer conversion (`float*` to `uint32_t*`) is where the UB originates.  Typically a `union`, when coded well, solves many issues.

Comment: Right you are, I got union and aliasing mixed up, that's pretty embarassing. Its funny because my original test executable actually used a union to prove that the code would work, then I rewrote it using aliasing to be more consice. Its the union that is IB, the aliasing that is UB. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Alternatively (modulo caveat about use of *non-standard* binary literal): `floaty = (floatint){.i = 0b11000011101010110010001000000000};` In practical terms, use of hexadecimal floating-point constants is typically preferred: `floaty.f = -0x1.564400p+8f;`